# How to fix wrong format of number when writing df to csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem writing my pandas dataframe to CSV. 
I could not find a similar question in the other topics.

In my command line output I have numbers varying from -4.5 to +4.5 and these numbers are good.

When I try to write my df to csv with the following code:

```
df13.to_csv("PlayerRatings3ZAT.csv", sep= ";", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Some (not all) of the numbers are shown to: 15352940000000000 but it must show: 1,5352940000000000.

However, most of the numbers are shown correctly. I can't figure out why I get some numbers not showing correctly.

Could you please help me out?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Because data related problem is necessary [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with problematic values.

Comment: Dear @Teunvdv, what is meant by `it must show: 1,5352940000000000`? You mean precision is not appearing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure of your encoding, Try this:

```
df.to_csv('pandasfile.csv', float_format='%.3f')
```

you might also consider: `float_format='%g'`

Comment: Thanks, but can you please share a piece of your data and code? To make it reproducible for us?